# Finding distance from point to line

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Knowing the position of 3 points($A, B, C$) , how can I get the distance from $A$ to the line $\overline {BC}$ if I know the angle?

Comment: [This Wolfram reference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html) was linked in [an almost identical question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15190/distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-in-space?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the positions as vectors, compute $\frac{|(A-B)\times (C-B)|}{|C-B|}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the equation of line $BC$ is $$ax+by+c=0$$ and $$A=(x_0,y_0)$$ then
$$d(BC,A)=\frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$